# How to make compound shapes in java which move together as one object?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a compound shape in Java, which is composed of primary shapes, but I want that the compound shape to behave as a single object. I have written a code to create a shape with circle and rectangle, but how can I make them to behave as a single object, because I want to move this whole shape, based on inputs. I am trying to implement parti
cle filter algorithm.

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ParticleFilter extends GraphicsProgram{

    public void run()
    {
        GRect boundary = new GRect(25,25,500,400);
        GRect robot = new GRect(50,70,40,40);
        GOval robothead = new GOval(60,60,20,20);
        add(boundary);
        add(robot);
        add(robothead);
    }

}
```

This is the code, I have been trying. Please let me know if you know how to solve this.

Comment: You could have a class with a list of `GObject`. Then, you have a method in that class that applies transformations to each `GObject` in the list.

Comment: @HugoSousa Can you please elaborate yourself a little more. I am not able to fully understand you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question correctly too. Let's say you have an object A, composed by B,C,D. You want to apply a move on A, and B,C and D perform the same move. Is that it?

Comment: Exactly. If I say move forward whole object A should move, not individual. So, how should I group B, C and D in such a manner.

Comment: Let me try to rephrase my first suggestion. You could have a new class, that represents the A. This class has a list with `GObject`, the B,C and D we talked. In that class, you could have a `move` method: this method would execute `move` on each element of the list (B, C and D), so they all suffer the same movement. Was that clear now?